# How does old wood furnace work?

Tags: wood, furnace

My mother in law has an old wood furnace in her workshop. It obviously is different than the typical wood stove you see. Does anyone have one of these? Or can anyone explain the theory behind its operation?  The top part is what has me slightly confused.  It seems like the smoke would come out the front of it as well as the back. 
Also, are they efficient? Burn good?

[image: front]
[image: side]
[image: back]

Comment: Well, obviously it isn't working; it's missing its Christmas Tree.

Comment: @DanielGriscom nice. The tree will go inside the stove in a few months. Do kinda regret my hasty picture and not taking the time for a cleaner shot.

Comment: I suspect it's coal, not wood, and the top is a weird one. Might try hearth.com and good close-ups of the flapper on the front and the name, etc. on the door. I think the secret to your "where the smoke goes" question lies in the front flapper and the fact that chimney's suck...but I have never seen one like that.

Answer (score 3):

I think that might be an old coal burner with a dome heat exchanger on top (also known as a radiator).

I have never seen or used one of these in person, but there is some information about this stove type sparsely spread around the internet.  I understand they are roughly 1940s vintage.

Consider this photo of a competing Wards model:

[image]

Ash tray is the bottom door.  Coal is added through the middle door and air inlet is controlled at the middle door and/or bottom door.   The top end is a heat exchanger that circulates flue gas to the center dome, then to the front part of the doughnut, around the sides, to the back, past a manual balancing damper at the flue connection and then up the chimney.  The manual balancing damper at the flue would be needed to manage airflow in concert with the intake.  I believe the front door on the dome is there for cleaning and remains closed during normal operation.

This stove is not likely to be efficient by today's standards because it is not equipped with a secondary burn chamber.

Comment: Thanks for the info! If this indeed is for coal, can wood be burned in it safely/properly? Would love to use it in a workshop. Also, the opening on the heat exchanger is cracked; not as tight as your picture, would that be a problem once the draft started?

Comment: Technically wood can be burned in many coal stoves, but wood tends to be dirtier and burn more quickly for the heat output compared to coal.  Preventing the convoluted doughnut heat exchanger from filling with creosote might also be problem.  I cannot comment on the crack you mention other than to say uncontrolled air infiltration into wood/coal burning appliances is generally a bad thing.

Comment: I can see creosote definitely being a legitimate concern with the exchanger. Another site said one negative is that wood has to be cut small to fit in the stove.

Comment: That crack would scare me. It could get bigger with heat, and you could have an accidental blast furnace on your hands. Hazardous on a cement floor; deadly if there's wood nearby. Bonus points for carbon monoxide leakage possibilities.

Comment: @chris I've been trying to figure out the "heat exchanger" you mention, but I figured it out: it's a radiator, and the heat is being transferred into the surrounding air. Might want to clarify that in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have one like the one in the bottom photo that I use in my shop.  It works great with firewood.  I would like to find some more information about it, like where and when it was made.  It has k-12 42 cast on the front.

Comment: Since you use one of these, can you address the OP question about how it operates?

Answer (score 0):

That looks a lot like an "octopus" furnace, missing all of it's sheet metal. It would have had a large "drum" around it. they worked by convection. Also known as a gravity warm air furnace sometimes. My house originally had one.

Answer (score 0):

I have something like this in my shop.  Different maker but very similar.  It could burn wood, coal, or oil.  Mine was made by Williamson metal company, Cincinnati, Ohio, in 1933.  It works great with wood.  I have a fire going right now so my dogs have a warm place to go.  It would have had some metal rings and sheetmetal to create a space around the furnace, leaving the access to the feed and clean out doors open.  It would have looked like an octopus with duct running to different areas of the basement, going to the different registers of the house.  Most likely the ducting would have been covered in asbestos, long before the dangers were known. I fell in love with the design and was thrilled to have a chance to own one.  I have only seen a salesman model of my stove and a few old advertisements.  I wish I knew more about the reasoning of the design of the register on top.  The top front opening is a clean out for the "donut".